# ion-toggle ionChange get called multiple times in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

**ion-toggle ionChange** get called multiple times in ionic. I have tried using different techniques to solve it but I am not successful.

**Code 1:**

```
     <ion-toggle
        (ionChange)="changeData()"
        color="success"
        checked="{{data}}"
      >
     </ion-toggle>
```

**Problem: When I used code 1 then ionChange get called multiple time and it does not show correct state first time.**

**Code 2:**

```
     <ion-toggle
        (ionChange)="changeData()"
        color="success"
        [(ngModel)]="data"
      >
    </ion-toggle>
```

**Problem: Code 2 causes infinite loop. It calls ionChange infinitly.**

If anybody has faced similar issue and/or anybody knows how to tackle it then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: can you include the code of `changeData()`?

Comment: yeah it sounds like its not that ionChange fires multiple times its the "data" changing which in turn causes ionChange to fire in response. Could you share full code including how "data" gets changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Infinite loop or multiple time calling of a method**  can be occurs if you are changing the the value of **boolean** in **(ionChange)="changeData()"** while you are already using **[(ngModel)]="data"** which is changing **boolean** value on **toggling**. So remove any code in your code which is changing data on **ionChange**.

I was facing similar problem when i was changing the value of boolean on **ionChange** while i was already using **[(ngModel)]**.

So remove any code similar to code below in **changeData()** method:

```
// remove code which is changing state again
       
 data = !data
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in the following way, remove the link from ngModel or checked with some variable. To go back to the previous state I map with the viewChild and control it from there.

Online test link
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-te4hb1?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts&theme=dark)